# How to create multidimensional associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hy guys,

I am studying javascript.

Is it possible to create this type of array?
where product code is replaced by values in particolar my variables cod_prodotto 
and not in a string like this.

```
var prezzo = $("input[name='prezzo']").map(function(){return $
(this).val();}).get();
var quantita_magazzino = $
("input[name='quantita_magazzino']").map(function(){return $
(this).val();}).get();
var cod_prodotto = $
("input[name='cod_prodotto_tmp']").map(function(){return $
(this).val();}).get();
  var myArray = new Array();
for (i=0; i<cod_prodotto.length; i++){
myArray[i] = {codice_prodotto:{'cod_prod': cod_prodotto[i], 
'prezzo': prezzo[i], 'quantita': quantita_magazzino[i]}};
}

[{codice_prodotto: {cod_prod: "S10_1949", prezzo: "98", quantita: "7276"}}, {codice_prodotto: {cod_prod: "S10_4757", prezzo: "85.68", quantita: "7302"}}, {codice_prodotto: {cod_prod: "S10_4962", prezzo: "103.42", quantita: "7302"}}] (3) (employer_page.php, line 261)
```

I would like to understand how to get for example the 98 values'.

Thanks all.

Comment: yes it is. If you provide a dataset and code of what you have done.

Comment: Let your code breathe mate, you'll suffocate. 

What you're asking for are arrays of objects, which Javascript certainly supports. Any type can be in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the array element by its index, and the object value by its name.
So you can access "98" value with this code :

```
arr[0].codice_prodotto.prezzo
```